# How to use Code from another Repository in Azure Devops Docker Build

Tags: python, docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I need to include code from another Azure DevOps Repo in a Docker Build step of an Azure Devops Pipeline.  Specifically, I have another repository that contains a python package that needs to be installed in a docker container. However, the Python package and the Dockerfile are in separate Azure Devops Repo's.

On my local machine I have [az](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli) and
[jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) installed, so I can grab a user token like this

```bash
TOK=$(az account get-access-token | jq -r .accessToken)
```

and use it to install the python package locally like this:

```bash
pip install git+https://${TOK}@dev.azure.com/MyTenant/MyProject/_git/MyPythonPackage
```

And likewise, I can add these steps to my Dockerfile:

```
ARG ACCESS_TOKEN
RUN pip install git+https://${TOK}@dev.azure.com/MyTenant/MyProject/_git/MyPythonPackage
```

and build the Dockerfile locally like this:

```bash
TOK=$(az account get-access-token | jq -r .accessToken)   
docker build --build-arg ACCESS_TOKEN=${TOK} .
```

However, when I try to do the same thing in my Azure pipeline like this:

```yaml
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: ANameLocalToThisPipeline
      type: git
      name: MyProject/MyPythonPackage
steps:
  - task: Docker@2
    displayName: Build the Docker Image
    inputs:
      command: build
      Dockerfile: "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Dockerfile"
      buildContext: "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/" 
      tags: |
        latest
      arguments: --build-arg ACCESS_TOKEN=$(System.AccessToken)
```

The docker build step fails with this message:

```
fatal: could not read Password for 'https://dev.azure.com': No such device or address
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that this happens because the service principal that is
used by your pipeline doesn't have permissions for the other repositories in
your project. A quick and dirty hack to get those permissions is to define
your other repository in the list of resources *and* check it out, like this:

```yaml
steps:
  checkout: ANameLocalToThisPipeline
```

Only *after* adding the checkout step will the pipeline realize it has insufficient
permissions and ask you to grant the required permissions to the pipeline's service principal.

To be clear, **without additional changes, your pipeline will still fail** because
adding a checkout step currently has several side effects that will break other parts of your pipeline.

However, after
your pipeline has run and failed, you can revert the pipeline definition to
the previous state, and the pipeline will retain the newly granted
permissions to your other repo, allowing your original pipeline to
successfully clone (via `pip install`) the other package the the Dockerfile
using the service principal (via `$(System.AccessToken)`)